# Playing a audio clip when my application starts.

Tags: java, android, audio

I am new to android development, I have looked at tutorials on implementing the audio files into Eclipse in a raw file, but all the tutorials I have seen are for audio clips on click I need the audio to start automatically when the application loads up

Help Please

Comment: Please don't do this. Most of us use our phones when we don't want sound blaring from the speakers. It's super annoying that every time I have to start a game, it starts playing its music until I can find the settings and disable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your audio file in raw folder

in Oncreate

```
MediaPlayer mPlay = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.youraudiofile);

    mPlay.start();
```

in on onPause

```
mplay.stop();
```

and in OnDestroy

```
           mPlay.stop();
        mPlay.release();
        mPlay = null ;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a tutorial that shows you how to play an audio clip when you click a button. Simply pick up the code from the `onClick()` event showed in the tutorial and move it to the `onCreate()` event of your Activity you wish to play the clip.

It shouldn't be that hard, really.